# Inconsistent sorting of Tailwind classes with prettier-plugin-tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css, eslint, prettier

The `prettier-plugin-tailwindcss` plugin is great for ordering classnames based on generated CSS order, but in my setup it's fairly inconsistent with the sorting for some reason.

In the example below where I'm setting up styles for a Heading component, it sorts `leading` and `text` classnames randomly.

[image]

Trying to resort causes a eslint prettier error.

[image]

It's not a problem only because it's harder to read the styles, but as we're using `twMerge` in all classnames, it **ignores** a `leading` classname if it's followed by a `text` one, as `text` also defines a specific lineHeight. So the optimal sorting I want would be `text-5xl leading-14`, for example.

I know I could use `important` styles or disable `font-size` in `conflictingClassGroups` for `twMerge`, but those don't solve the root reason of unstable sortings.

Edit: updating both `prettier-plugin-tailwindcss` and `tailwindcss` packages to latest didn't solve it

Comment: By now I fixed the leading being ignored by transforming className into an array, where text styles go in the first string and leading in the next one, like ['text-5xl', 'leading-14'], which forces that order